# link foreign keys from tables using visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, database-design, visual-studio-2012

Im trying to create a simple page that displays a patch database using my patch table below
these are my current tables

```
 Software: Id(PK), name, description

 OperatingSystem: ID(PK), name, description

 Patch: ID(PK) Software_ID(FK), OperatingSystem_ID(FK), Version, Notes
```

My patch table displays when its run however i want the patch table to show the software name and operating system name instead of the software id & operating-system ID so the data makes sense when being displayed. I'm assuming i have to somehow link them as foreign keys?

I'm using visual studio 2012

what I've done so far

- a blank aspx page with my database inserted using SQL data source
- created my tables in server explorer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **`JOIN`** the 3 tables to bring data from all those tables. The below query will give you data with Software name and operating system name.

```
SELECT P.ID as PatchID,S.Name as SoftwareName,O.Name as OperatingSystem,
P.Version,P.Notes From Patch P
INNER JOIN 
Software S ON P.Software_ID=S.ID
INNER JOIN
OperatingSystem O ON P.OperatingSystem_ID=O.ID
```

Now you should write code to execute this query and read the result using a data reader and show data from that in the page. You may use a grid control such as Repeater/ DataList. there are plenty of examples in internet how to do that. just do a search and try yourself. Goodluck.

Comment: hi thanks for reply. i know i use a join but where do i use it? which part should i be looking to use this code. I have the design code for each table and a aspx doucment

Comment: @user2152448: Drag and drop a gridview to your page. In the code behind, in the page load event, you can execute the code to get data from your database. and bind it to your datagrid.

Comment: @user2152448: Check this http://programmingshare-thienle.blogspot.com/2011/12/get-data-from-sql-database-and-display.html

Comment: ok ive made a grid view. and in my source of my aspx i have this code currently "SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [patch]". is this where i should look to add the joins?